# Sonar analysis successful but not seeing report-task.txt file

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I am running sonar analysis on PR jobs using jenkins freesytle project.  sonar analysis is running fine, after run it is showing as

```
[INFO] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL
```

But in the next line it is throwing

```
WARN: Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succeed?
```

Not able to understand what is wrong here. This is the command i am using.

```
$SONAR_MAVEN_GOAL -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL -Dsonar.github.pullRequest=$ghprbPullId -Dsonar.github.repository=$ghprbGhRepository -Dsonar.github.oauth=$oauth -Dsonar.login=$login -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview -Dsonar.stash.notification=true -Dsonar.inclusions=$inclusions -Dsonar.test.inclusions=$testInclusions -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false -Dsonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports -Dsonar.skipDesign=true -Dsonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco -Dsonar.jacoco.reportPath=target/jacoco.exec -Dsonar.jacoco.itReportPath=target/jacoco-it.exec -Dsonar.surefire.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports
```